# Spaces are not recognised in the same way in a txt file and in a command line

Tags: bash, whitespace, file-format

I am using Mac. I have compiled a bytecode `run`, it can work on a string input in a command line like:

```
./run "Here is a text input"
```

To test `run`, I write `inputs.txt` that contains sever lines of inputs, one line represents one input:

```
"input1"
"This is input 2"
"input 3"
```

And, here is a `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line";
    ./run $line
done < inputs.txt
```

The problem is that, a test fails for input lines that contain space, although testing the same line in the command works.

So I guess, space is not interpreted the same when it is in `inputs.txt` and in a command line.

Does anyone know what to do to make spaces in `inputs.txt` interpreted in the same way as in a command line? Maybe should I change the format of `inputs.txt`?

Comment: could be a quoting problem.  get rid of the quotes in the input file, then add them to the script: `./run "$line"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to change

```
./run $line
```

to

```
./run "$line"
```

That way, the use of `$line` won't be split into arguments before run is called.